# Enter superscript in textfield

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

How can I enter a superscript in a text-field in blackberry cascades. I am making a small maths apps and need to enter some text in superscript(variables power)? If this is not possible can you suggest some possible workaround. I am using these in a list too, so I would prefer if rich text is not used.

Comment: Maybe a split view could work, similar to the answer preview here in SO or other sites and forums, you could use an standard text field and show the preview in a label with an HTML text mode, the super index text should be sorrounded with the <sup></sup> tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML text styling (including CSS) for certain widgets with text ie `Label`, `TextField` etc. Not sure if there's a tag for superscript since tags support is quite limited, but it's worth to have a look at available ones:

http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/ui/text/styles.html (scroll down to HTML text styling section)